# "Why" in a non-question sentence

Tags: word-usage, interjections

I am reading a book and I am finding this kind of expressions:

- '**Why**, people in perfect health act in the same way too,'
- '**Why**, are you all afraid of me?'
- 'What nonsense he is talking! **Why**, you are in a sentimental mood today, are you?'
- 'And why should they compensate me? **Why**, he was drunk and threw himself under the horses'

My wondering is about the use of the bold "why". I understand it as an expression, perhaps equivalent to "ah?" or "what?", but I am afraid my understanding is not correct or inaccurate. Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interjection "to express surprise, hesitation or impatience."
Link: [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/why)

Answer (score 0):

You're perfectly correct.

Try substituting "What's the matter," "What" (you mention it yourself), "No way," "Look," "Whoa!" etc.

Comment: It is the first time I see such expressions. Is it currently use in the english literature or in a coloquial conversation?

Comment: I could imagine Jane Austen (18t century literature) using it, but it might also be used in some dialects too. I've got a feeling you might come accross it in some old classic Hollywood movies. People I know use it sometimes for fun/ironically.

Comment: "What's the matter, are you afraid of me?" - sounds perfectly normal in today's English, New York overtones and all.

Comment: Would you also say (without irony) Why! Are you afraid of me?

Comment: @BurNor It ("why") seems slightly dated, at least in British English. I can imagine it in an Agatha Christie or PG Wodehouse novel.

Comment: Yes, that's how I see it too. I wonder if US Americans still use it. I could easily picture, say, Kathrin Hepburn in an old movies saying something like 'why, you're all cold. What's the matter?'

Comment: In the American South where there is no wine-whine merger, this _why_ is pronounced as the letter y, while interrogative _why_ has the historic wh-sound.